# MySQL - using LEFT JOIN gives unexpected results

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

I have two tables orderedproducts and productsinstocks. here is the table structures:

orderedproducts table:

```
+-----+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| id  | orderid | productid | quantity | productgroup |
+-----+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 117 | 1016186 |    265385 |        5 | Main         |
| 118 | 1016186 |    407454 |        6 | Main         |
| 119 | 1016186 |    975045 |        7 | Main         |
| 120 | 1016186 |    975046 |        8 | Main         |
+-----+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

productsinstocks table:

```
+----+---------+-----------+----------+
| id | stockid | productid | quantity |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+
| 20 |  903958 |    265385 |      200 |
| 21 |  903958 |    407454 |      205 |
| 22 |  903958 |    975045 |      210 |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+
```

As you see, the stock has only three types of products in orderedproducts table. I want to JOIN these tables to achieve the following result:

```
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| orderid | productid | stockid | order_qty | stock_qty  |
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| 1016186 |    265385 |  903958 |         5 |       200  |
| 1016186 |    407454 |  903958 |         6 |       205  |
| 1016186 |    975045 |  903958 |         7 |       210  |
| 1016186 |    975046 |  903958 |         8 |       NULL |
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

I used the following query:

```
SELECT op.orderid, op.productid, plo.stockid, op.quantity order_qty,  plo.quantity stock_qty FROM orderedproducts op
LEFT JOIN productsinstocks plo
ON op.productid=plo.productid
WHERE op.orderid=1016186
AND plo.stockid=903958
```

but it gives me the following result:

```
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| orderid | productid | stockid | order_qty | stock_qty  |
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| 1016186 |    265385 |  903958 |         5 |       200  |
| 1016186 |    407454 |  903958 |         6 |       205  |
| 1016186 |    975045 |  903958 |         7 |       210  |
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

I don't know What I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT op.orderid, op.productid, plo.stockid, op.quantity order_qty,  plo.quantity stock_qty FROM orderedproducts op
LEFT JOIN productsinstocks plo
    ON op.productid=plo.productid AND plo.stockid=903958
WHERE op.orderid=1016186
```

Answer (score 5):

The following condition in your `WHERE` clause is responsible for the missing record in your result set:

```
WHERE plo.stockid = 903958
```

The missing record in the `orderedproducts` table does not match to any record in the `productsinstocks` table.  Therefore the `stockid` value for this record will be `NULL` and your current `WHERE` condition will filter it off.

Instead, add a check `OR plo.stockid IS NULL` to the `WHERE` clause to retain this record:

```
SELECT op.orderid, op.productid, plo.stockid, op.quantity order_qty,
       plo.quantity AS stock_qty
FROM orderedproducts op
LEFT JOIN productsinstocks plo
    ON op.productid = plo.productid
WHERE op.orderid = 1016186 AND
      (plo.stockid = 903958 OR plo.stockid IS NULL)
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: This still generates the same result set.

Comment: Are you sure you copied my exact query?  It should be working AFAIK.

Comment: yeah I copied and pasted what you sent.

Comment: @MehdiB The query works for me, at least using the exact data which you pasted.  Have a look at the Fiddle demo I included in my answer.

Comment: You're right. It's working on sqlfiddle but why is it not working for me? I'm using wamp with mysql 5.6. strange!

Comment: @MehdiB Only you can answer that.  Try taking the `CREATE TABLE` from my Fiddle and use them in your MySQL database.  There could be an issue with your data.

Comment: Well I think I found the problem. This solution works (as you said) only when the tables contain the above mentioned data. however the productsinstocks and orderedproducts contain data corresponding to other stocks and orders, making this solution not to work.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets see what **WHERE** and **ON** clauses do

**Where** clause decides which rows to be selected for the output.

**ON** clause decides which rows the to be selected for the join.

```
WHERE plo.stockid=903958
```

This part of **WHERE** clause eliminates last row from the output.

Here we want to select rows before join operation. So, lets move conditions from **WHERE** to **ON** clause.

```
SELECT op.orderid, op.productid, plo.stockid, op.quantity order_qty,  plo.quantity stock_qty FROM orderedproducts op
LEFT JOIN productsinstocks plo
ON op.productid=plo.productid AND plo.stockid=903958 AND op.orderid=1016186
```

Also, you should expect **stockid** as **NULL** and not **903958** in the last row.